# Allocating for double struct pointer in function

Tags: c, struct

I am allocating memory for my `struct test` containers in function. But I am not sure whether the result is undefined behavior or
is it some other mistake.

First I created a reference pointer

```
  struct test **x;
```

Then I allocated 10 pointers and each pointer will suppose to point to single `struct test` at [0] index. Like this:

```
 x=malloc(sizeof(struct test *) * 10);
```

So x[0] will be the only `struct` in container in *x
and x[0] for next container (*x+1)

So now each container struct item I like to allocate in another function. So I assumed already that I should pass the address of x like `get_s(&x,0x00200000);`

So my function declaration need to be `int get_s(struct test ***arr,int n)`. Is this correct understanding?

Then I address the real pointer x as in main like (*arr+i) in function as `i` increments from 0 to 9 in  loop but I need now to allocate `struct test` single item in each container so I need single loop and another starik sign to locate my struct in containers.

So my function became something like this:

```
int get_s(struct test ***arr,int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        //each pointer will point to single struct test
        *(*arr+i)=malloc(sizeof(struct test));
        (*(*arr+i))->a=n;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

But I am not sure about this. and the first value in main is simply garbage value printing. So what's wrong with following code?

When compiling it does not report any error.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct test{
     uint32_t a;
    };  


    int get_s(struct test ***arr,int n)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            //each pointer will point to single struct test
            *(*arr+i)=malloc(sizeof(struct test));
            (*(*arr+i))->a=n;
        }
        return 0;

    }


    int main()
    {
        struct test **x;
        //allocated 10 pointers for arr[0] to arr[9] , is this correct? 
        x=malloc(sizeof(struct test) * 10);

        //alloc_populate(&x,10);
        get_s(&x,0x00200000);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {       
            printf("%x\n", x[i]->a);
        }   
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so my function declaration need to be int get_s(struct test ***arr,int
> n) so is this correct understanding?

There is no need to use 3 stars because you are simply modifying the contents of the array, not the value of the passed pointer, your function can look like:

```
int get_s(struct test **arr, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ;i++)
    {
        // each pointer will point to single struct test
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
        arr[i]->a = n;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then, from `main`, just pass the pointer itself and not a reference to the pointer:

```
get_s(x, 0x00200000);
```

Answering your comment in code:

```
struct test **x;
//allocated 10 pointers for arr[0] to arr[9] , is this correct? 
x=malloc(sizeof(struct test) * 10);
```

no, is not correct, you want:

```
x = malloc(sizeof(struct test *) * 10); // space for 10 pointers to struct test
```

or better yet:

```
x = malloc(sizeof(*x) * 10); // space for 10 pointers to struct test
```

Notice that your example, as is, doesn't need an array of pointers, why not an array of `struct test`s?

```
int get_s(struct test *arr, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        arr[i].a = n;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct test *x;

    x = malloc(sizeof(*x) * 10);
    get_s(x, 0x00200000);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {       
        printf("%x\n", x[i].a);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get lost with too much dereferencing...

The simplest way to learn may be to study a working version...

```
struct test {
    uint32_t a;
};

void get_s( struct test *arr[], int size, int initial ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        arr[ i ] = (struct test*) malloc( sizeof( struct test ) ); // point to single
        arr[ i ]->a = initial;
    }
}

void main( void ) {
    const int nElem = 10;
    //allocated 10 pointers for arr[0] to arr[9] , is this correct?

    struct test **x = (struct test **)malloc( nElem * sizeof(struct test *) );

    get_s( x, nElem, 0x00200000 );

    for( int i = 0;i < nElem; i++ )
        printf( "%d - %x\n", i, x[i]->a );
}
```

You should check that `malloc()` isn't failing and returning NULL...